# GCC version 4.9 has no installation candidate

Tags: bash, gcc, g++, apt, package-managers

I'm trying to install gcc version 4.9 on Ubuntu to replace the current version 7.5 (because Torch is not compatible with version 6 and above). However, even following precise instructions, I can't install it. I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo aot-get remove gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9.
```

Note that I already have CUDA installed. When I try installing version 4.9., it gives this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-hppa-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-m68k-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-sh4-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-mips64el-linux-gnuabi64' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-hppa64' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-sparc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-powerpc-linux-gnuspe' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-s390x-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-mips64-linux-gnuabi64' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-powerpc64le-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-powerpc64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-sparc64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-mipsel-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-alpha-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-mips-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabi' for regex 'gcc-4.9.'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-cudart-10-2 cuda-cudart-dev-10-2 cuda-cufft-10-2 cuda-cufft-dev-10-2
  cuda-cuobjdump-10-2 cuda-curand-10-2 cuda-curand-dev-10-2 cuda-cusolver-10-2
  cuda-cusolver-dev-10-2 cuda-cusparse-10-2 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-2
  cuda-driver-dev-10-2 cuda-gdb-10-2 cuda-libraries-10-2
  cuda-libraries-dev-10-2 cuda-license-10-2 cuda-memcheck-10-2
  cuda-misc-headers-10-2 cuda-npp-10-2 cuda-npp-dev-10-2 cuda-nsight-10-2
  cuda-nsight-compute-10-2 cuda-nsight-systems-10-2 cuda-nvdisasm-10-2
  cuda-nvgraph-10-2 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-2 cuda-nvjpeg-10-2
  cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-2 cuda-nvml-dev-10-2 cuda-nvprof-10-2 cuda-nvprune-10-2
  cuda-nvrtc-10-2 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-2 cuda-nvtx-10-2 cuda-nvvp-10-2
  cuda-sanitizer-api-10-2 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 freeglut3-dev g++-7
  libcublas-dev libcublas10 libnvidia-extra-440 libxi-dev libxmu-dev
  libxmu-headers libxt-dev nsight-compute-2019.5.0 nsight-systems-2019.5.2
  nvidia-compute-utils-440 nvidia-kernel-common-440 nvidia-kernel-source-440
  nvidia-modprobe nvidia-utils-440 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

For whatever reason, it does not want to install it. When I type `sudo apt-get install gcc` on the other hand, it just re-installs version 7.5.
What can I do to replace GCC (and G++) with version 4.9?

Comment: This might help: [Install gcc 4.9 at ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1036108/336375)

Comment: I checked it too, but it does not exactly represent my issue since it discusses G++ not GCC and also only provides a solution for version 4.8

Comment: Replace `g++-4.9` with `gcc-4.9`. Works fine with Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: It says "gcc-4.9 has no Installation candidate".

Comment: I suggest trying to use Torch with a more recent GCC. It probably would work; you might otherwise recompile either Torch or GCC from its source code.

Comment: Torch is buildable from its source code, except for Lua (they don't document what version of Lua they need).

Comment: Also you have typo in your apt-get install command with dot at the end "gcc-4.9." instead of just "gcc-4.9" and that's why apt-get is saying it is selecting different packages for "regexp gcc-4.9.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC 4.9 repo is still available officially just add these in your repo

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

Then update and install again.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I figured out myself. You must add however that strangely, G++ and GCC version 4.9 is still not available, you must go with 4.8. By combining multiple sources, I constructed a way to install G++ and GCC 4.8.5 on your machine and configure them as the default ones:

```
# Remove old packages and install new ones
sudo apt-get remove gcc g++
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 build-essential
# After this however, you can only access it with specifically calling for 'gcc-4.8' and 'g++-4.8'. So we set them default
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
```

When we now type `gcc --version`, we get:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

more specific for A2:

1.su to root, and modify /etc/apt/sources.list by adding

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

2.update the source by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3.install

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
```

Comment: The same answer was already posted in July, you just added  apt-get update and install which are already mentioned in the question itself. Please find other questions, to which your answers can be helpful.